# How to pass multiple classNames as props with css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-modules

I can't seem to understand how to pass a string with multiple classNames as a prop using css modules? I have different classes i use everywhere for the button, and so i have on class for when it's active, and another when it's inactive. I also have different color schemes i pass.

Button:

```
import styles from "./Button.module.css";

const Button = (props) => {


  return (
    <button className={`${styles.standardButton} ${styles[props.className]}`}>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

And here is the page which uses the button. The button function is at the bottom, and some input fields needs to be filled out in order for it to be "active".

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Input from "../input/Input";
import Select from "../input/Select";
import Button from "../input/Button";

const CreateJobPage1 = (props) => {
  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = useState("");
  const [enteredCompany, setEnteredCompany] = useState("");
  const [enteredLocation, setEnteredLocation] = useState("");
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const [projectType, setProjectType] = useState('DEFAULT');

  const projectTypes = ["shortfilm", "fiction", "commercial", "arthouse", "animation"];

  const nameChangeHandler = (props) => {
    setEnteredName(props);
  };
  const companyChangeHandler = (props) => {
    setEnteredCompany(props);
  };
  const locationChangeHandler = (props) => {
    setEnteredLocation(props);
  };
  const textChangeHandler = (props) => {
    setEnteredText(props);
  };
  const projectTypeHandler = (props) => {
    setProjectType(props);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <Input
          placeholder="What's the project name?"
          enteredValue={enteredName}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="What's the production company?"
          enteredValue={enteredCompany}
          onChange={companyChangeHandler}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Where's the project located?"
          enteredValue={enteredLocation}
          onChange={locationChangeHandler}
        />
        <Select
          placeholder="Choose project type"
          options={projectTypes}
          value={projectType}
          onChangeOption={projectTypeHandler}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="What's the project about?"
          enteredValue={enteredText}
          onChange={textChangeHandler}
          formulaType="textarea"
        />
        <Button
          className={enteredName === "" || enteredCompany === "" || enteredLocation === "" || projectType === "DEFAULT" ? ["isRed", "formButton", "inActive"] : ["isRed", "formButton"]}
          text={"Add Functions"}
        />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateJobPage1;
```

Comment: CSS modules provide properties that represent the class names. There is unlikely a CSS module property named `isRed formButton inActive`.

Comment: The solution is to iterate over the list of classnames passed as a prop. Consider changing the space separated list of strings into an array to make that easier.

Comment: Those are represented in the Button.module.css file, but only they are separated, i do know i should pass them as individual classNames as an array, but i still don't know how they should be added in as props..

Comment: I've also tried mapping it out; 

className={`${styles.standardButton} ${props.className.map(s => styles[s])}`}


But that throws an error

Comment: I think instead of passing in the class name you need for the element, you should just pass in a boolean as props to control the style? smth like
```
`${ isActive && styles.inActive.}`
```

Comment: @EmilWoxen if you do the map for the style. style will be decode to the actual classname first: for example styles.isRed will be smth like `src-pages-DemoCalculator-DemoCalculator-module__isRed--ngoXq ` and when you return them with the map, there are no space between your `actual` className, so add ```+ ' '``` when you return
in your example will be 

```javascript
${props.className.map(s => styles[s]+" ")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const classNameTest = ['isRed', 'fontColor']
<div className={`${styles.cardWrapper} ${classNameTest.map((item) => {
          return styles[item] + ' '
        })}`}
      >
```

As I mentioned above in the comment,  all the styles in `xxx.module.scss` is mean to prevent different style files have duplicate className and they will effect each other globally. when you do `styles.isRed` the REAL class name will likely to be `src-pages-YourFileName-module__isRed--SOMEUNIQUECODE`

1. when you try to pass them as props, u still need to access them by import `styles`
2. when you do a map return u need to have space between each `return` so at the end html will know they are different class
3. I still think is better to pass the `status` like `isActive` to control the component style. otherwise this component is not really fit the idea of a component